# Imported raster images appear as placeholders

Tags: inkscape

I want to import a raster image into Inkscape. But whenever I do "File - Import..." the image gets imported as a placeholder (see screenshot below). Is this some kind of compatibility issue or do I need to activate the actual view? I am using Inkscape 1.2 together with Arch Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're in outlines-only view. Click on 'View → Display Mode → Normal' to disable it.

If you want to stay in the outline display mode, but want imported images to show regardless, open the preferences, go to 'Imported Images' on the left and enable the 'Render Images in Outline Mode' setting. You'll have to toggle outline mode off and on again for it to take effect.

Comment: Perfect, very helpful!